# How to apply regexp in mysqli statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm using pure php and not any CMS such as Wordpress.

I have a product table where there is a cat field for Categories of the product.

I have a page view that is based on a category. So, for instance I want to see all mobile phone with brand of Nokia. It means

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE cat = nokia.
```

This works just in cases where the product is not multi-category. If the following product is categorized like this: `Nokia, black, new, expensive, top-rated`; then I need to use regexp in my SQL statement. For instance something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat *= Nokia.
```

My cat field of product table is a string *with each cat separated by comma*.

Is it correct? What should I do?

Comment: There are [lots of questions related to this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+match+value+in+comma+separated). `FIND_IN_SET()` is offered by MySQL, but [the real answer is _not_ to store your data this way and instead properly normalize the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: The [MySQL docs on `FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you plain `like` clause

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE cat like '%Nokia%'
```

Or use [mysql regex feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), if you like

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE cat REGEXP '.*Nokia.*'
```

And, yes, your data model is ill - you should use 1 or 2 more tables instead of comma separated strings in `cat` field.

**ADDITION:**

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE (cat like '%Nokia,%' or cat like '%,Nokia%')
```

in ANSI SQL, or

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Nokia',cat)
```

with MySQL-specific feature - all 4 queryies given above are ineffective like hell and can not be optimized without changing data model.

Assuming you have two tables `products(product_id,product_name,...)` and `categories(cat_id,cat_word,...)` you can simple relate them throug third [associative table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) `product_in_categories(product_id,cat_id)`

And an example of effective category-selection query with new data model:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
WHERE exists(select 1 from categories c, product_in_categories pc 
  where cat_word='Nokia' and c.cat_id=pc.cat_id and pc.product_id=p.product_id)
```

Comment: Sorry what is your suggestion? I have a table called category but I do not know how to relate them.